How to write a gc log to a file in container while running a spring boot application
Getting below error in the container logs and the applications is not booting up when i have added the java command in Deployment.yaml file
-Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*=debug:file=gc-debug.log'
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dspring.profiles.active=it
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*=debug:file=gc-debug.log', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[0.001s][error][logging] Error opening log file 'gc-debug.log': Permission denied
[0.001s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=gc-debug.log' using options '(null)' failed.

Did you read the error message? "Permission denied" --- check what user runs this in what directory and adjust permissions as needed. (You probably also want to make sure you mount the log directory in a way that it persists the container shutting down, if you haven't already.)
